# not calling php script from shell script which installed in crontab

Tags: php, linux, cron

i have move_files.sh and installed it in crontab.

Actually job is working because it's printing those echo. And creating log file.
But it's not calling that PHP script. 
Interesting thing is if i run it by manually it's calling php script and working 100%. But why it's not calling after i installed it on crontab. 
should i put "php" before calling php script. I am thinking that cronjob would work same as manually running script. Please give me idea.

My code is below.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

DIR=/data/aa/bb
LOG=~account/HOME/log/dd
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
LOG_FILE=$LOG/move_files.$DATE.log
PROG=~account/HOME/bin/move_files.php

for type in "1" "2" "3" 
do
  echo "Check files in $DIR/dat/$type" >> $LOG_FILE
  $PROG $DIR/dat/$type $DIR/backup/$type >> $LOG_FILE

  echo "Compress files in $type" >> $LOG_FILE
  find $DIR/backup -name "*.DAT" -type f -exec gzip -f {} \;  >> $LOG_FILE
done
```

Comment: first isn't it `~/account`. check selinux logs if it is `enforcing`. Always use full path for files when running from cron job

Comment: @bansi ~account is valid, it means "the home directory of user 'account'".

Comment: @GeraldSchneider  yes. I agree with you. Otherwise it shouldn't create log file.

Comment: I was just reconfirming. You need check your selinux logs. cron jobs have different permission than user shell. I had same problem even when the cron was running as root.

Comment: just try `sealert -a` on the audit log eg: `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log`. You may need root permission for this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue as you're doing. My backup script was working very well if it's called directly but wasn't working in crontab at all. I figured it out by adding this in the start (after shebang) of bash script:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt
```

Where "/opt" in the last is the directory where my bash script exists.

Comment: You mean like this.
My script is under /home/account/HOME/bin

#!/usr/local/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/account/HOME/bin
DIR=/data/aa/bb
LOG=~account/HOME/log/dd
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`

Comment: `PATH` is not required when using full paths in the script.

Comment: @user347918 yes this should work, for the next time surround the code with back-ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the script specifying php binary path.

```
/path/to/php_binary script_file.php
```

E.g:

```
/usr/bin/php5 myscript.php argument1 argument2 >> mylogfile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the script locally, you will visit to that folder (i.e. ~account/HOME/bin/)

By executing cron, it will use a new shell to execute the *.sh file in the present path. Therefore what you missing is to visit the path of where the *.php/*.sh file is contained. (absolute path is recommended)

```
cd ~account/HOME/bin/
```

The log file can be created because you issue an environment variable $LOG which indicates the exact location of that log file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,
anyway i put on myscript following line:

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

Then it's working now.

Thank you all of you guys.